# Latin Character Inbetween String

Tags: java, parsing, latin

I have a program to read in a file which contain latin words such as "\xed". These latin words can appear anywhere in between any line, as such I have program parsing these character. Is there any library that can do so?

Comment: What do you mean by in between?

Comment: I didn't know `\xed` was a latin *word*. What does it mean?

Comment: @Andreas, just found out that it should be parse to \u00ed which is a "Latin Small Letter I with acute"

Comment: @LJNielsenDk, example i have K\xedng which should be Kíng

Comment: Are you saying it contains the *string* "K\xedng", or is it containing the *bytes* `4B ED 6E 67` ("Kíng")?

Comment: @Andreas, nope. i guess is the original file parsing. I overcome by replaceing "\x" with "\u00" and do a StringEscapeUtils.

Answer (score 0):

The simple way I often do is InputStreamReader with "UTF8" format. For example:

```
         try {
            File fileDir = new File("c:/temp/sample.txt");

            BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(
                    new InputStreamReader(
                            new FileInputStream(fileDir), "UTF8"));

            String str;

            while ((str = in.readLine()) != null) {
                System.out.println(str);
            }

            in.close();
        } 
        catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) 
        {
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        } 
        catch (IOException e) 
        {
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you mean that the text is in bytes and you have a byte with the hex value `ED`, then the interpretation of that byte depends on your code page.

Java stores all `String`'s internally in UTF-16. This means that a code page conversion is pretty much always applied when reading and writing file (UTF-16 is not a common file encoding).

By default, Java will use the *platform default* character set. If this is not the correct one, you have to specify the `Charset` to use.

As an example of the problem, byte `ED` is:

- ISO-8859-1:  `í` (unicode `00ED`)  US Windows
- Windows-1251:  `н` (unicode `043D`)  Russian
- Code page 437:  `φ` (unicode `03C6`)  US Windows command-line (Win 7)

To control the code page, read the file like this:

```
File file = new File("C:\\path\\to\\file.txt");
try (BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(new FileInputStream(file), "ISO-8859-1"))) {
    String line;
    while ((line = in.readLine()) != null) {
        // process line here
    }
}
```

Or with the newer `Path` API:

```
Path path = Paths.get("C:\\path\\to\\file.txt");
try (BufferedReader in = Files.newBufferedReader(path, Charset.forName("ISO-8859-1"))) {
    String line;
    while ((line = in.readLine()) != null) {
        // process line here
    }
}
```

Comment: I guess if the entire file is in ISO8859 format your method will work prefectly! however, my file is a mixture of iso8859 and utf8

Comment: @chj Surely you're joking. UTF-8 uses bytes 80-FF and so does ISO-8859-1. How are you supposed to know if a byte in that range is one or the other?